# Office 2010 activation from domain group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

We just found out that an windows 7 image that we had applied to about 1,800 laptops has a bit of a problem.  When Students log in for the first time an lauch word, they are prompted to activate office but can't because they done' have admin rights.

Here is a script that runs the activation"

c:\windows\system32\cscript C:\"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OSPP.VBS" /act

My question is this, if I run this under another account on the individual laptops, does that script effect all the user profiles?  If NOT can I run this script from a domain Group Policy and have it run even though the user does NOT have admin rights?

Thanks in advance.

Zyper Thanks for your answer but I'm little fuzzy about how to post this via group policy and run it as a "system" user.  When you say "system" are you refering to the computer configuration or the user configuration?

Comment: At the risk of sounding condescending (which is not my intention, but speaking from personal experience) you could have saved yourself a lot of headaches by testing this deployment before going live with 1800 machines.

Comment: Oddly enough we did and it ran fine.  What I think happened was the wrong HD shipped to the manufacture.  Lucky for me there were only a couple minor problems.

Answer (score 9):

> My question is this, if I run this under another account on the individual laptops, does that script effect all the user profiles?

Yes, activation is per machine, not per user.

> If NOT can I run this script from a domain Group Policy and have it run even though the user does NOT have admin rights?

I believe that if you run it as a start up script  (runs as the `SYSTEM` user) and not a logon script it should work.

Comment: I was going to post essentially the same answer, but I'll give you a one up instead.

Comment: Zypher.  Thanks for your help.  So where do put this in the GPO?  I'm a little fuzzy as to where to place the script to run it as "system".  Do you mean under the computer configuration?

Comment: Any  start up or shutdown script is run under the `SYSTEM` account since there is no active user to associate with the action. This is opposed to Logon and Logoff scripts which run as the logged in user.You can find the setting at: `Computer Configuration->Policies->Windows Settings->Scripts`

Comment: So would I be right in assigning the GP to machines rather then users?

Comment: You are Correct Sir.

Answer (score 2):

If you have that many installations then KMS is something you should (already) have in place.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2009/08/24/volume-activation.aspx

Comment: The KMS server solution is what you are looking for. This also applies to virtual desktop solutions so users aren't prompted for activation during their initial logins.